# How Many Russian Citizens Live in Crimea?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, crimea

It is reported that about 60% of the population in Crimea (Ukraine) are Russians. My question is: How many percent of the population are Russian *citizens*?

Comment: Not sure but I have heard that during conflict they were giving out more citizenships in that area so they could say "we protect our citizens"

Comment: Most of them are citizens of Ukraine

Answer (score 11):

Noone knows this 100% exactly.

Many people have both Ukranian and Russian passports.

And they will not answer you honestly how many passports do they have.

Russian and Ukrainian governments do not exchange this data between each other.

As mentioned, Russia's policy is to give Russian passports to as more people as possible. Empire buys citizens. And then uses this fact to attack.

I have some friends and also some relatives there.

And as far as I can say, **not more then 20%** of Crimean people **really have** Russian citizenship.

But at least 70% support everything Russia do and dislike Ukraine. They are being **Russian in their mind**. They think that all of their problems are because of independent Ukraine, and they want back to Soviet Union because Russian TV and Media day and night shout out how good it was and how good it would be if USSR was back again. Russia was spending a lot of money to 'hypnotize' Crimean people, Ukrainian security service ignored this fact, and this is the result..

Separatism banners examples:

[image: Banner example 1]

[image]

Crimean people meet Russians:

[image]

**SMALL UPDATE**

One more new poster from Crimea:

[image: Poster]

It says: on March 16 we select between this and that.

As lord Churchill said, fascists of the future will call themself antifascists.

Comment: What do the poster and billboard say?

Comment: Do you have citations for the statistics?

Comment: he didn't say that all Crimeans dislike Ukraine

Comment: @RazieMah, poster says "Stable Russia - stable Ukraine"

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov The only city that was seriously destroyed is Debaltsevo... And guess, who did it in Feb, 2015 ?  Also, about Nazi. Nazi? No, sir, nazi had some ideas and principles. But thanks to Russia, now most people in Ukraine open their eyes and understand that Russians are not brothers and are not our friends at all.

Comment: @RazieMah ...and: March 16 we are deciding

Comment: @Anixx, oh don't worry, even if they didn't, after several Ukrainian acts of "love and support" like cutting of water, electricity and food trade they certainly do.

Comment: "...Russian TV and Media day and night shout out how good it was and how good it would be if USSR was back again..." - this is simply not true...